# Include ModelState.IsValid in controller unit test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mstest

I have the following controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginUseraccount loginUseraccount)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Do something
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something
            return RedirectHomeIndex;
        }
    }
    catch (UserNotActiveException userNotActiveException)
    {
        //Do something
        return RedirectHomeIndex;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Do something
        return RedirectHomeIndex;
    }
}
```

I have three questions:

1) Would you define two tests for the if-else?
The first test would test ModelState.IsValid == true, the other test ModelState.IsValid == false? Wouldn't it make more sense to test this in the unit test written for the model?

2) Would you test the UserNotActiveException? If an exception is thrown is decided by the business logic (other class). So it would make more sense to do this test in the business logic test, do you agree?

3) Would you test the Exception? I think this doesn't make sense.

I know there's no "right" or "wrong", but I really would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: 1 yes, although the else is redundant since the if returns. 2) yes, 3, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should test everything.
It will not take much efforts and time but bring a good level of confidence into your code.

1. I think you definitely should do this.
2. You should test not the cause of the exception, but the behavior of your controller in case of exception. So your test should verify that in case of `UserNotActiveException` controller returns the appropriate `ActionResult`.
3. Same as second point.

Comment: Thank you! About point 2: I don't know how to reproduce that an exception is thrown. So I won't be able to test this part of the code. Or is there a possibility to force the method to throw an exception?

Comment: It depends on what is going on inside `//Do something` :) and who is throwing this exception.

For example, assuming you have some `IBusinessLogicService` interface with `Login` method (and this method is throwing this exception) and you are using this service inside controller to perform necessary logic, you can mock this interface so that for particular unit test it will always throw an exception of desired type.

Comment: "Exception" is not thrown anywhere in our code. It's just to ensure that in the controller every exception is found. But I can't reproduce a thrown exception. :(

Comment: Yes, it will be hard to test this. So you can consider redesigning.
For example you can move this logic about general Exception in action filter and apply it to controller or action or register as global filter. Then you can easily test action filter and action itself as this logic will not present inside your action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback and effort. I marked your answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly write to unit tests for the if/else clause. You want to ensure that all logic is covered in your tests, but that it should be done separately, not in the same test.

As for the exceptions, again I would test for those. You could use [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) to help with unit testing your action methods, to check which routes, or views, are returned e.g. RedirectToHomeIndex. I would do this as piece of mind that I'm confident the action methods do what I expect them to. If any test fails, then I know that the user may be redirected to a different page than I wanted.